# Pass value to lightning components from vf page Salesforce

Tags: visualforce, apex, salesforce-lightning

Pass value to the attributes of a lightning component from the visual force page.

Answer (score 0):

> inside vf page at some function call below code where c:dependancyapp is app and c:demoComp is component you need to add dependency of component inside app(c:dependancyapp) using dependany tag
>
> dependancyapp App below

```
<aura:application access="GLOBAL" extends="ltng:outApp"> 
<aura:dependency resource="markup://c:demoComp" type="COMPONENT"/>
</aura:application>
```

> VF page at some action in js

```
 function clickMe(){
 $Lightning.use("c:dependancyapp", function() {
 $Lightning.createComponent("c:demoComp",
      { "someAttribute" : "attribute value"},
        "lightning",
         function(cmp) {
            // do some stuff
       });
   });
  }
```